# Clarification needed in second parameter to List.init (F#)

Tags: list, f#

Could you explain the second parameter in List.init

`let test2 = List.init 100000 (fun _ -> System.Random().Next(-50, 51));;`

From the declaration of List.init [available here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.init%5B%27t%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D); what I understand is that init takes an `int` and "a function that takes an index and returns a generic value" as parameters. The return value is a list of the generic type passed.

But I don't understand how is the function being applied in the given `let` binding.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List.init` takes an integer for the size of the list and then a function that will be used to fill each element. This function takes in the current index of the element being filled (ie. an int). The Type of the elements in your list then depends on the return type of the 2nd function. In your case an `int`.

In the example in the question the function `fun _ -> System.Random().Next(-50, 51)` will just pick random value to fill the list with. Since it is new-ing up `Random` every time you will get the same value every time because computers and randomness are not very well acquainted. the `_` is used in many languages to indicate that we don't care about the value of the parameter because we are not going to use it. So here `_` is used as an anonymous generic parameter.

For an actual "random" value you could move the `Random()` call outside the function and close over it or you could technically use the item index as a seed number. I am not recommending this but it does illustrate what that function takes.

```
let test1 = List.init 100000 (fun i -> System.Random(i).Next(-50, 51))
```

As I mentioned something like this is more likely what you are after:

```
//Random
let random = System.Random()
// int -> int 
let generate (_:int) = random.Next(-50, 51)//note this has the signature we need for the 2nd parameter of List.init
// generate the list
let test2 = List.init 10 generate;;
```

The `_` can also be used in matching. Here we have a tuple we want to deconstruct to get to it's values.

```
let person = ("Bob","Builder")
let (firstname,lastname) = person
let (_,surname) = person
```

If we don't care about the firstname we don't have to get it but can still use the same syntax, we just use `_` to indicate we do not care about the value.

Reference [Symbol and Operator reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/symbol-and-operator-reference/)

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand now. `fun _ -> System.Random().Next(-50, 51)` is an anonymous function that uses _ as a wildcard placeholder for parameter and returns a random number.

So, it can be used as second parameter to init, and get a list of randomly generated integers back.